SymmetricDS is not reflecting data from source to target node
I am implementing symmetric-ds, everything is fine the nodes, the triggers, but the synchronization is not working.
sym_outgoing_batch has many rows but the values are not reflecting to the target database
I have made entries to all the relevant tables according to the documentation but its not working

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What’s in the logs? Any exceptions? Has the destination node registered?

@BorisPavlović
First of all it says (http://localhost:31415/sync/dm-001 is not working for ):
dm-001 is my target node.
[dm-001] - SymmetricServlet - Requests for engine dm-001 are being rejected while it is starting
[emr-000] - PushService - Remote node dm:001:001 at http://localhost:31415/sync/dm-001 was unavailable

It says Remote node dm:001:001 at http://localhost:31415/sync/dm-001 was unavailable but the command create-sym-tables does create the tables in the target node (dm-001) and makes an entry into the sync_node and sync_node_security tables

Please edit the original question by adding the logs and the stack trace
